# I want to start my Spring Application Context from Groovy Script

Tags: java, spring, groovy

I have an implemented and running stable application in Java. This java application uses Spring Context and in my other project I have to startup this java application using Groovy Script. But Spring XML in Java Application uses Environment Variable like below

```
<util:properties id="props" location="file:${external.config.dir}/$[ext.errors.file]"/>
```

I don't wanna update my java application with this change.

**How can I pass environment variable to Groovy Script and startup Spring Context properly?**

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using JAVA_OPTS?  As far as I know groovy passes them onto the JVM.  You can also pass `-D...` directly on the command line.